# Javascript post back of parent page from child page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On Button Click I am calling this JavaScript Method from Child(aspx) page.

```
 function closechildwindow() {
            window.opener.document.forms(0).submit(); 
            self.close();
        }
```

Its closes the child Page and its also makes a post back on the parent page. But the parent page is open in a separate Tab.

I don't want this. I want that post back to happen on parent page in same tab that is already open, and should not open in new tab.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

What you need is calling the `__doPostBack()` Javascript function on the parent window:

```
window.opener.__doPostBack();
```